# Generate numbers based on pattern

Tags: ruby

I want to generate four digit numbers (from `0000` to `9999`) that look like `ABCD` and `AABC`.
So for example the pattern `ABCD` will have numbers like

`0123`,`0124`,`0125`,`0126`,`0127`,`0128`,`0129` so on.

Pattern AABC like:

`0012`,`0013`,`0014`,`0015`,`0016` etc.

Comment: Can you provide some sample of code to understand your approach ?

Comment: Don't know what do you need. A generator with equal probability to yield every string, or just generate them all?

Comment: sample code that I went ahead to generate ABCD.
('0000'..'9999').each{|x| x if x =~ /^(?!.*(.).*\1)\d{4}$/}

and I'm looking to generate them all(resulting Array)

Comment: If they are padded with leading `0`, then they are not numbers but strings.

Comment: thanks for your helpful comment, I guess u know what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(0..9).to_a.permutation(4).map{|a, b, c, d| [a, b, c, d].join}

(0..9).to_a.permutation(3).map{|a, b, c| [a, a, b, c].join}
```

Or

```
(0..9).to_a.permutation(4).map{|a, b, c, d| "#{a}#{b}#{c}#{d}"}

(0..9).to_a.permutation(3).map{|a, b, c| "#{a}#{a}#{b}#{c}"}
```